# Django test global setup

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have some file for unit test with django:

test1.py

```
class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        ...
```

test1.py

```
class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       ...

    def tearDown(self):
        ...
```

testn.py

```
class Testn(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       ...

    def tearDown(self):
        ...
```

I want to create a **global setup** to make some configuration for it all test, someting like:

some_file.py

```
class GlobalSetUpTest(SomeClass):
    def setup(self): # or any function name
         global_stuff = "whatever"
```

is that possible? if so, how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just create a parent class with your custom global `setUp` method and then have all of your other test classes extend that:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.global_stuff = "whatever"


class TestOne(MyTestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        a = self.global_stuff 


class TestTwo(MyTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Other setUp operations here
        super(TestTwo, self).setUp() # this will call MyTestCase.setUp to ensure self.global_stuff is assigned.

    def test_two(self):
        a = self.global_stuff
```

Obviously you could use the same technique for a 'global' `tearDown` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it only run once for all tests, you can override the test management command by placing a `management/commands/test.py` in one of your apps:

```
from django.core.management.commands import test

class Command(test.Command):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Do your magic here
        super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
```

Unfortunately this does not work well with PyCharm.
In PyCharm you can use the "[Before Lunch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)" Task instead.